# What is the advantage of registry discovery service versus api gateway?

Tags: java, spring, microservices

A discovery server allows a client to discover existing services. It does not depend on a fixed url.
However an api gateway with routing function also allows to contact services with only a url.
In one case as in the other the client depends on a url so what is the difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the registry discovery service is to discover services for which the IP is not known and to monitor them.

The purpose of the API Gateway is to serve as an entrypoint for the client. It can handle things like authentication, logging, request filtering, etc, before redirecting the client to the appropriate service.

These types of services have different purposes and usually work together, so it's not one versus the other.

---

For example, let's imagine the following scenario with 5 services:

- API Gateway
- Registry Discovery Service
- Authentication Service
- Customer Service
- Adds Service

The client would call the API Gateway. For each request, the API Gateway would validate the request, if not authenticated, it may redirect the user to Authentication Service, and if authenticated it redirects the user to either Customer Service or Adds Service depending on the url pattern. To find the actual addresses of the target Service it uses the Registry Discover Service.

Comment: One question I could not find an answer to is, how is the Registry Discovery Service itself discovered? Since it is a service itself and could possibly have multiple instances, how does the API Gateway and other microservices know the endpoint of the the discovery service?

Comment: @racerX If there are multiple Registry Discovery Services, the clients can connect through a Load Balancer which will route to one of the available Registry Discovery Services. The load Balancer however will have to know the endpoints of these services.